# Progress Bar with PV & Zenity using md5sum

Tags: bash, zenity

I'm trying to write a script for get `md5sum` of unique files or multiples files inside a directory in the cli using `pv` to see the progress bar, and in gtk because I use Xfce 4.12 (Slackware64 14.2) in `zenity`.

Well the things I don't make it work are:

1. `zenity` progress.

   I try during last 12 hours a method for redirect the percentage of `pv` to a file `/tmp/zenity.prg` in reverse order with `tac`, and after use `cat` in a loop with `sleep 1`, waiting a new line add to the `/tmp/zenity.prg` file for use with `zenity` to make the progress bar move.

   The idea was [use the example of site Zenity of Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/progress.html.en):

   ```
    (
    echo "10" ; sleep 1
    echo "# Updating mail logs" ; sleep 1
    echo "20" ; sleep 1
    echo "# Resetting cron jobs" ; sleep 1
    echo "50" ; sleep 1
    echo "This line will just be ignored" ; sleep 1
    echo "75" ; sleep 1
    echo "# Rebooting system" ; sleep 1
    echo "100" ; sleep 1
    ) |
    zenity --progress \
    --title="Update System Logs" \
    --text="Scanning mail logs..." \
    --percentage=0

    if [ "$?" = -1 ] ; then
            zenity --error \
            --text="Update canceled."
    fi
   ```
2. A part of code I found on xfce if I don't miss but equal this part of code don't work for me, that is for the multiples files.

   Well the code I had right now is this :

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    echo '
    Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
    Sitio ----------------> https://goo.gl/ij6WqW
    Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
    Licencia -------------> GPL 2'

    #Variables Principales
    Archivo="$@"
    Cantidad=$(ls "$Archivo" | wc | awk '{print $1}')

    #Determinar Cantidad de Objetos
    if [[ $Cantidad -eq 1 ]]; then
    Cantidad=$Cantidad
    fi

    if [[ $Cantidad -gt 1 ]]; then
    Cantidad=$(ls "$PWD" | wc | awk '{print $1}')
    fi

    hash zenity 2>/dev/null
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Zenity no esta instalado!"
    echo "Por favor instale Zenity"
    exit 1
    fi

    if [[ "$Cantidad" = "0" ]]; then
    zenity --error --text="Nada para calcular!"
    fi

    if [[ $Cantidad -eq 1 ]]; then
        (for Unico in "$Archivo"; do
        pv -- "$Unico" | 
        md5sum | 
        tee >(cut -d ' ' -f1 > /tmp/sumd5) |
        sed 's/-$//' |
        printf '%s%s\n' "$(cat -)" "$Unico"
        sed -n 'H; 1h; $!d; g; s/\\/\\\\/g; s/\n/\\n/g; t x; p; q; :x s/^/\\/; p;'
        done) &

        #Zenity
        (while [ -f /tmp/zenity.prg ]
        do
            cat "/tmp/zenity.prg" ; sleep 1
        done) | zenity --progress --title="Suma de Integridad MD5" --text="Calculando MD5 de:\n${Archivo##*/}" --percentage=0 --auto-close 2>&1 |
        #Zenity

        if [ "$?" = -1 ] ; then
                zenity --error --text="Proceso Cancelado por el Usuario."
                rm -rf /tmp/sumd5
                rm -rf /tmp/zenity.prg
                exit 0
        fi

        sumd5=`cat /tmp/sumd5`
        zenity --info --title="Suma de Integridad MD5" --text="$sumd5\n\nArchivo:\n${Archivo##*/}"
        rm -rf /tmp/sumd5
        rm -rf /tmp/zenity.prg
        exit 0
    fi

    if [[ $Cantidad -gt 1 ]]; then
    if zenity --question --title="MD5sum" \
                --text="Seleccion Multiple.\nEsto creara/reemplazara un archivo llamado <b>multiples.md5</b>\nen el directorio donde estan estos archivos.\n¿Desea Continuar?" \
                --no-wrap
        then
            > multiples.md5
            i=0
            TOTAL="$Cuenta"

            while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
                    ((++i))
                    PERCENT=$(($i*100/${TOTAL}))
                    echo "#md5sum $i/$TOTAL: $line"
                    md5sum "${line}" >> multiples.md5 2>&1
                    echo "$PERCENT"
            done < "$Archivo" | zenity --progress --title="MD5" --auto-close

            exo-open 'multiples.md5' || zenity --text-info --title="Sumas de Integridad : MD5" < multiples.md5
    fi
    fi
   ```

The main idea of this script is just for use with contextual menu, but I prefer have scripts can work without a filemanager like : Thunar, Caja, Nautilus, Dolphin.

Comment: i recommend to remove your email from question